# Вопрос про Highcharts

Tags: php, json, highcharts

Пытаюсь построить график, беру вот такой код из примера:

```
Highcharts::widget([
   'options'=>'{
      "title": { "text": "Fruit Consumption" },
      "xAxis": {
         "categories": ["Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges"]
      },
      "yAxis": {
         "title": { "text": "Fruit eaten" }
      },
      "series": [
         { "name": "Jane", "data": [1, 0, 4] },
         { "name": "John", "data": [5, 7,3] }
      ]
   }'
]);
```

Массив для `series` формирую вот так:

```
public function collectDataFromQuery($array) {

    $resultData = [];

    foreach ($array as $arrayItem) {

        $resultData[$arrayItem['idinvite']]['name'] = $arrayItem['address'];
        $resultData[$arrayItem['idinvite']]['data'][] = $arrayItem['fromwhere'];
    }
    return $resultData;
}
```

В итоге получаю `json` вида

```
{
    "series": {
        "217": {
            "name": "https://zen.yandex.ru/example.ru",
            "data": ["35", "27425"]
        },
        "233": {
            "name": "https://news.google.com/publications/example",
            "data": ["6", "19817"]
        },
        "106": {
            "name": "https://www.facebook.com/example/",
            "data": ["9", "6848"]
        },
        "232": {
            "name": "https://news.yandex.ru/index.html?from=rubric&favid=example",
            "data": ["3", "4748"]
        },
        "118": {
            "name": "http://instagram.com/example",
            "data": ["7", "16439"]
        },
        "45": {
            "name": "https://chat.whatsapp.com/example",
            "data": ["10", "22222"]
        },
        "158": {
            "name": "https://chat.whatsapp.com/example",
            "data": ["3", "2272"]
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "http://t-do.ru/example",
            "data": ["268"]
        },
        "117": {
            "name": "https://twitter.com/example",
            "data": ["190"]
        },
        "115": {
            "name": "https://vk.com/example",
            "data": ["223"]
        },
        "116": {
            "name": "https://ok.ru/example",
            "data": ["2743"]
        },
        "119": {
            "name": "http://chats.viber.com/example",
            "data": ["345"]
        },
        "188": {
            "name": "https://tamtam.chat/example",
            "data": ["209"]
        },
        "156": {
            "name": "http://t-do.ru/example",
            "data": ["8"]
        },
        "157": {
            "name": "http://t-do.ru/example",
            "data": ["118"]
        },
        "0": {
            "name": "",
            "data": ["7"]
        },
        "231": {
            "name": "https://news.yandex.ru/example",
            "data": ["1"]
        }
    }
}
```

В `xAxis:` `categories` подставляю такие данные

```
{
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": {
            "0": "2018-10-01",
            "7": "2018-09-01"
        }
    }
}
```

Но по этим данным график не строится. Предполагаю, что дело может быть из за индексов, но я не знаю как от них можно избавиться и действительно ли в них дело. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ряды должны быть в таком виде:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    }]
```

А категории простой массив строк:

> categories: [
>               'Jan',
>               'Feb',
>               'Mar',
>               'Apr',
>               'May',
>               'Jun',
>               'Jul',
>               'Aug',
>               'Sep',
>               'Oct',
>               'Nov',
>               'Dec'
>           ],